# Regexp to match file ending with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the file endings from some files in a list.

```
<a href="myfile.mp4">File 1</a>
<a href="http://www.files.com/myfile.ogg">File 2</a> 
<a href="myfile.mp3">File 3</a>
<a href="http://www.site.com/myfile.jpg">File 4</a>
```

Basically, the file endning could be anything, and the string can contain more than just one ".". So I need to fetch the ending only.

I want to get a result that looks like:

```
mp4
ogg
mp3
jpg
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the extensions for all links in a document like this:

```
var endings = [];
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var matches;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].href) {
        matches = links[i].href.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/);
        if (matches) {
            endings.push(matches[1]);
        }
    }
}
// the array endings contains a list of all link extensions
```

Here's a working version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XHKaT/

The regular expression here matches a period followed by one or more non-period characters at the end of the string.  The parenthesized grouping allows us to extra just the extension without the period which accomplishes the result you outlined.

Comment: @Esailija - I figured any real world example probably scopes the desired links more narrowly than the entire document so the OP can specify what starts out in the links array however is appropriate.  I don't think that's the interesting part of the solution that the OP was asking for.  They most wanted to know how to extract just the extension from a given link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to:

1. Get all of your anchor elements.
2. For each element you can access the .attr("href") value which will be your address string i.e. "myfile.mp3"
3. Then you can split the string on "." character and add the value at tokenArray[tokenArray.length-1] to your result list.

Or for vanilla JS try:

```
function getExtensions(){
    var allAnchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var extensions = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < allAnchorTags.length; i++){
        var tokenArray = allAnchorTags[i].href.split(".");
        extensions[i] = tokenArray[tokenArray.length-1];
    }  

    return extensions;
}
```

which does the same as described in my algorithm except with vanilla JS syntax. Give it a shot

Comment: Yes, jQuery is great, but I can only use core JS in this particular case. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok so I've added an example of the original algorithm in vanilla JS syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This function performs as you need without reporting duplicates and maintaining the order in which the filename extensions are discovered.

```javascript
function getLinkedFileExtensions() {
  var i, len=document.links.length, ext=[], exts={};
  for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var a = document.links[i];
    if (a.href && a.href.match(/\.([A-Za-z0-9]{1,4})$/)) {
      var x = RegExp.$1;
      if (!(x in exts)) {
        exts[x] = true;
        ext.push(x);
      }
    }
  }
  return ext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ext = [].map.call(document.links, function (a) {
    return (a.href.match(this) || [])[1] || "";
}, /\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/).filter(String);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZ9cU/

Answer (score 0):

**See** [**Feedle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tmcxq/)

```
var ext = a.href.split(".");
ext = ext[ext.length -1];
console.log(ext);
```

**EDIT :**

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    ext, i, j;

for(i = 0, j = d.length; i<j; i++){
            ext = d[i].href.split(".");
            ext = ext[ext.length -1];
            console.log(ext);
 }
```